# Finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a skew field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups

It is well known that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic, but this certainly fails for skew fields (look in the quaternions for an easy example). Yet there are constraints on what finite subgroups of multiplicative groups of a skew fields can be: for example, every all their abelian subgroups must be cyclic (this follows readily from the above result).

Is there a nice characterization of such subgroups, or at least some interesting constraints on them? I'd be surprised if any finite group with all its abelian subgroups cyclic occurred as such a group, though I don't have a counterexample. I'm also curious about the simplest example of such a group which doesn't come from the quaternions, and results that extend for infinite subgroups.

Comment: You mean you would be surprised if all groups with abelian subgroup occurred as such groups. You have just proved that there is such an example. (I recommend avoiding the word "any" in mathematical statements.)

Answer (score 8):

Let $G$ be a group such that all abelian subgroups are cyclic. Then in particular, $G$ has no subgroup of the form $C_p\times C_p$ for any prime $p$. This means that the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are cyclic for $p$ odd, and cyclic or generalized quaternion for $p=2$. That's all you can say about the structure, since if $H$ is an abelian subgroup it factorizes as the direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups, and is cyclic if and only if all Sylow $p$-subgroups are cyclic.

So what is the structure of such groups? If the Sylow $2$-subgroup is also cyclic then $G$ is soluble, and in fact has a normal subgroup of odd order and index a power of $2$. Even more, it is actually supersoluble, which you can see once you know it's soluble. If $G$ has generalized quaternion Sylow $2$-subgroups then more examples can occur, such as $\mathrm{SL}_2(p)$.

A paper by Suzuki, *On finite groups with cyclic Sylow subgroups for all odd primes*, Amer. J. Math. 77 (1955) 657–691, examines this case. He finds that if $G$ is not soluble then it possesses a subgroup $G_1$ of index at most $2$, and $G_1$ is a direct product of a group of odd order and a subgroup $\mathrm{SL}_2(p)$.